# Deleting consecutive vowels from char array

Tags: c

So I have a homework asking to remove all vowels in a string w/o using an additional string. My problem is that I wanna make it working even if I have some consecutive vowels like aabbbceee, I want it to print bbbc but instead of that it would print something weird.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isVowel(char a) { 
    if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u') return 
       true;
    return false;
}

void main () {
    char* sir = (char*)calloc(256, sizeof(char));

    scanf("%[^\n]s", sir);

    int numarVocale = 0, lungimeSir = strlen(sir);
    for (int i = 0; i < lungimeSir; ++i) {
        if (isVowel(sir[i])) numarVocale++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lungimeSir; ++i) {
        if (isVowel(sir[i])) {
            int pozitie = i;
            pozitie++;
            while (isVowel(sir[pozitie]) && pozitie < lungimeSir) {
               pozitie++;
            }
            sir[i] = sir[pozitie];
            sir[pozitie] = '\0';
       }
   }

   sir = realloc(sir, lungimeSir - numarVocale);

   printf("The string after I deleted the vowels: %s", sir);
}
```

My thinking was to find a first vowel, then save its position and if next character is also a vowel loop through them until I find a consonant.

Comment: Please show the exact code you are running. Don't try to type it from memory or anything like that. The code shown will not compile as it has syntax errors `strlen(sir);`. Which indicates that's not your exact code. Also, please include the complete code (looks close but is missing the `isVowel` function definition, some header includes and end of function).

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to make a simple translation from my native language and I forgot to edit that "sir". I will just add the missing parts.

Comment: Would suggest you simplify things to start with by not treating repeated vowels as a special case. Just treat each letter seperately.

Comment: `str[pos] = '\0';` Why do you do that? That will immediately truncate the string and lose all the characters from `pos` onwards.

Comment: I am sure I am running the exact code. I just copy-pasted it now.

Comment: I don't know what character to use to replace it. Thats why I did that.

Answer (score 1):

`sir[pozitie] = '\0';` is what's messing with you.

Try walking through an example on paper.

`aabbbceee` will find that `a` is a vowel at the beginning.

```
while (isVowel(sir[pozitie]) && pozitie < lungimeSir) {
    pozitie++;
}
```

The above code runs until it finds the first `b`. `sir[i] = sir[pozitie];` replaces your `a` with `b` so now you're looking at `babbbceee`.

`sir[pozitie] = '\0';` then replaces the first `b` with `\0`. Now you're looking at `ba\0bbceee`.

You advance to the next vowel, which is the second `a`. You then look for the next character that fails `IsVowel()`, which is the `\0` you just inserted. At the end of this if-statement, you're now looking at `b\0\0bbceee`.

At this point you should be able to see the error in your logic. As for what it's outputting, it only shows the first consonant because `\0` is the terminating delimiter for C strings. So, `printf()` only sees `b\0` and prints `b`.

Comment: And what should I replace '\0' with?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to *count* the number of vowels beforehand.

Just do a single loop and process one character at a time.

There's no need to use `strlen`. Just stop the loop if the current character is EOS (e.g. 0).

The important point is to *not* copy the current character *if* it *is* a vowel.

Maintain *two* index variables: (1) the source/input index (e.g. `isrc`) and (2) the destination/output index (e.g. `idst`).

Only advance `idst` *if* you're copying a character (i.e. a non-vowel).

A refinement is to *not* copy the character if `idst` is `isrc`. (i.e. you'd just be copying the same character to itself). But, you still have to *increment* the output index (`idst`).

And, you have to add a new EOS (string terminator) at the end of the loop.

Here's the refactored code (with some annotations):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool
isVowel(char a)
{
    if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u')
        return true;
    return false;
}

void
main(void)
{
// NOTE/BUG: don't cast the result of malloc
#if 0
    char* sir = (char*)calloc(256,sizeof(char));
#else
    char* sir = calloc(256,sizeof(*sir));
#endif

    scanf("%[^\n]s",sir);
    printf("The string before I deleted the vowels: '%s'\n",sir);

    int isrc = 0;
    int idst = 0;

    while (1) {
        // get next char (and advance the source index)
        char chr = sir[isrc++];

        // end of string
        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        // skip any vowel
        if (isVowel(chr))
            continue;

        // copy over char [if different]
        // NOTE: using the "if" is a nicety/speedup
        if (idst != (isrc - 1))
            sir[idst] = chr;

        // advance destination index
        ++idst;
    }

    // add EOS to new [possibly] shorter string
    sir[idst] = 0;

    // trim the output string
    sir = realloc(sir,idst + 1);

    printf("The string after I deleted the vowels: '%s'\n",sir);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check it when I get home.